# MySQLi / PHP - Altar post table depending on comment table query

Tags: php, mysql

it's me again!

So my issue this time is I want to delete a user and have the option to keep their comment or not when they are deleted. My issue is that I don't know how to decrease the comment count by 1 in the posts table depending on the comments table. I'll explain further...

I have a user (users table) with userid 1.

I have a post (posts table) with postid 1 and comment count as 2.

I have a comment (comments table) with commentid 1 and authorid 1.

If I want to delete the comment along with the user, how do I say decrease comment count by 1 in posts table where the authorid in the comments table equals userid 1?

Example query although it won't work as it's not finished, hence this post...

`mysqli_query($sql, "UPDATE " . $dbprefix . "posts SET count = count - 1 WHERE authorid = '$deletedUserId'") or die(mysqli_error($sql));`

Do let me know if you don't understand. It's a bit of a tricky one to get my head around. If I'm correct I need to alter two tables in one MySQLi query statement.

Thank!

**edit 1**

Okay so I have the following...

Post 1 called Test with a post id 1 with a comment count of 1

User 1 called John with a user id 1

Comment 1 that says Hello World which was posted by user id 1

I need to essentially have a query that says, find all comments posted by the user with a user id of 1 and decrease the comment count by 1 in all posts where that user has made a comment to them.

So, delete user 1 and delete all of their comments which will have an author id of 1 and decrease the comment count on each post by 1 as well.

Comment: what happens when you run that query?

Comment: The comment is deleted but the comment count stays the same, so the count is not being decreased by 1.

Comment: Need more details on your table structure. You are trying to get update your posts table but using where clause authorid (table comments). Its just sounds wrong

Comment: should you have a space before `posts` in your query?  It looks like your `$dbprefix` might be running together with `posts`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll update the first post and try make it clearer. @Will the dbprefix is fine, it's suppose to add on mytable_ (for example) as a prefix so that's not the issue.

Comment: Maybe you can try to give a relation DB. e.g what is postid? Is it a combination comment id and authorid? or .....

Comment: Post id is simply just the id number of the post. So comment 1 has an author id of 1 and is related to post 1 which has a post id of 1.

Comment: "Post id is simply just the id number of the post.". Then how to link it with another table? I mean how to decide "abcd" posts comment is from "Mr.Dan" author?

Comment: Because in the comments table there is a post id column and that post id relates to a post in the posts table with the same id if that makes sense? So postid and postid in both the posts and comments table are the same, which is how they are linked together.

Comment: I see, now it makes sense thats why need more details on table structure. Try this: `mysqli_query($sql, "UPDATE " . $dbprefix . "posts SET count = count - 1 WHERE postid = (select postid from comments where authorid = '$deletedUserId'")) or die(mysqli_error($sql));`

Comment: That did it! THANK YOU SO MUCH :D Yep, it reduced the comment count by 1 in each post where the user had made a comment. Perfect! :)